# Recompile Apache22 with threading seamlessly?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, apache-httpd, bsd

I just found out today that our apache installation was installed without threading support (we need this for mod_wsgi).

Will the following in the apache22 ports folder reinstall our apache with threading support? More importantly, will it do it seamlessly (leaving mod_wsgi working, http_root in tact etc?).

```
make configure      // Select thread support
make
make deinstall
make reinstall
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above commands worked.
Some forum posts seemed to suggest that ports doesn't mess with any files you've touched (therefore you're configuration files are saved).